# Double exclamation in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I know when double exclamation is printed, it executes the previous command. But echo !! gives some strange results which I don't understand. 
For example when typed below command in bash script, it prints echo too as part of the output

```
echo $$
echo !!
This prints the below output:
echo echo $$
echo 3150
(Why does echo precede every output ?)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you use history substitution, the shell first displays the command that it's about to execute with all the substitutions shown, and then executes it. This is so you can see what the resulting command is, to confirm that it's what you expected.

So if you type:

```
some command
echo !!
```

the `!!` is replaced with the contents of the previous command. So it displays and then executes

```
echo some command
```

Comment: It prints the command that it's about to execute. `!!` is replaced with the previous command.

Answer (score 5):

It's caused by history expansion. Quote it instead:

```
echo '!!'
echo \!\!
```

Or disable history expansion:

```
shopt -u -o histexpand  ## Or
set +H
```

See [History Expansion](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bash/html_chapter/bashref_9.html#SEC115).

Comment: This is not quite right. There are no exclamation marks in his previous command, so history expansion does not apply here. It simply prints out the result of the substitution (which is the command it is about to execute) and than the result of the commands execution.

Comment: @Danagon I think I might have misperceived the question and my answer may not apply, but history expansion still applies _here_. The substitution you speak of is a form of history expansion. I don't see how your idea "There are no exclamation marks in his previous command" makes sense in this case. Also FYI: it's officially called "history expansion", not "history substitution" as mentioned in the other answer.