# Is this a bug or something unintended with memory?

Tags: c, bash

I wrote a simple C program that takes any number of text parameters and echos them out.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  for (int i=1;i<argc;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<strlen(argv[i]);j++){
      printf("%c", argv[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Running the code, it seems to be working as intended, such as

```
$./echo hello world
hello world
```

But if I add exclamation marks to the input, it goes haywire.

```
$./echo hello world!!
hello world./echothehelloworld
```

And the more exclamation marks I add at the end, it repeats to the output exponentially.

Comment: `!` is a special character to your shell.  See [**Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)

Comment: Not related to the C program, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980679/double-exclamation-in-bash-script/24980706

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html

Comment: @JohnBollinger, note that double-quotes _don't_ work to disable history expansion, that would still expand the last command within the double quotes. You need to use single quotes or backslashes instead. Or just `set +H` to get rid of the whole blasted thing for good.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your arguments, an unquoted or double-quoted `!!` gets replaced by the shell with the last command you ran, if [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) is enabled (it is by default in an interactive shell).  Aside from quoting the `!` to prevent history expansion for one command, you can disable it for the current shell with `set +H`.

A common use of `!!` is to run the last command with root privileges like this:

```
$ whoami
marco
$ sudo !!
root
```

Your C code is fine, this will work as intended (note the double quotes):

```
$ ./echo "hello world!!"
```

Comment: double-quotes don't work to stop history expansion, see e.g. [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html): "When using the shell, only [backslash] and `'` may be used to escape the history expansion character,"